# How to read Video from Google Cloud Storage without downloading it? using video URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, google-cloud-storage

I want to read a video file using opencv but the problem is that the video is on my Google Cloud Storage, and `opencv.videocapture` method won't recognize it.
Is there any other way to access video file without downloading the video on a local disk?

I also tried with `urllib.urlopen` but it didn't work.
Here's my code:

```
import urllib
import numpy as np
import cv2

uri = 'gs://call-gestures/dictionany/AIDS.mp4'
url = "https://storage.cloud.google.com/call- 
gestures/dictionany/AIDS.mp4?authuser=1"
# Open a sample video available in sample-videos
r = cv2.imread(url)
print('Result: ',r)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
print(cap)
if cap.isOpened():
    print ("File Can be Opened")
    while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        #print cap.isOpened(), ret
        if frame is not None:
            # Display the resulting frame
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            # Press q to close the video windows before it ends if you want
            if cv2.waitKey(22) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            print("Frame is None")
            break

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print ("Video stop")
else:
    print("Not Working")
```

Errors I got:

```
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:901)
warning: https://storage.cloud.google.com/call-gestures/dictionany/Asia.mp4?authuser=1 (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:902)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to read a video file stored in google cloud storage without downloading it, via generating a signed url.

**Google storage bucket structure**:

[image]

**Code**(Tested):

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import storage
import datetime

import urllib.request as req
import cv2

cred = credentials.Certificate('Path\to\your\google-credential-file.json')
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'storageBucket': 'cnc-designs.appspot.com'}, name='storage')
bucket = storage.bucket(app=app)

def generate_image_url(blob_path):
    """ generate signed URL of a video stored on google storage. 
        Valid for 300 seconds in this case. You can increase this 
        time as per your requirement. 
    """                                                        
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_path) 
    return blob.generate_signed_url(datetime.timedelta(seconds=300), method='GET')


url = generate_image_url('sample1.mp4')
req.urlretrieve(url, "sample1.mp4")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('sample1.mp4')

if cap.isOpened():
    print ("File Can be Opened")
    while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        #print cap.isOpened(), ret
        if frame is not None:
            # Display the resulting frame
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            # Press q to close the video windows before it ends if you want
            if cv2.waitKey(22) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            print("Frame is None")
            break
    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print ("Video stop")
else:
    print("Not Working")
```

Library needs to be installed:

**firebase_admin**: `pip install firebase_admin`

Comment: Thank you so much <3 this is what I want.. :)

Comment: This is not true, the line "req.urlretrieve(url, "sample1.mp4")" downloads the content locally and then plays it.

Answer (score -1):

yes. you need to use Google Storage Public URL

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('https://storage.googleapis.com//your_Bucket//sample1.mp4')
```

[image: 1]